# How to hide and unhide left side menu bar in odoo 11?

Tags: odoo

I want to hide and un hide left side menu bar in odoo 11. If it can be hided pls suggest me how to do?[like in the picture, i want to hide purchase order left side bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emzcN.png)

Comment: provide your code, what you tried, the error you got etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is one application available in Odoo store which hides sidebar, you can try that if it can help you for you requirement.
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/tgk_hide_left_sidebar/

Comment: thanks. but i cannot pay. i am in learning process. if possible kindly give me ideas to create my own module to hide and unhide side bar